# required data structure for Excel stacked bar chart

Tags: excel, stacked-chart

I am working in Excel 2013.  I have the following data structure:

```
column A          column B        column C
Key               Dimension       Date
1                 a               1/2/2019
2                 a               1/3/2019
3                 b               1/1/2019
4                 a               2/5/2019
5                 b               2/20/2019
6                 b               2/1/2019
```

I want to create a stacked bar chart of the count of Key, by month-year (from Date) as my horizontal axis, and Dimension as my legend.  How can I do this?  From the tutorials online, all I can find is how to create stacked bar charts from some sort of pivot table.

Comment: First if you are looking to group your data by month-year, you will need to have an extra column to help you filter your data. Something like "=YEAR(C1)&"-"&MONTH(C1)"



Secondly, you will need to count how many "Key" falls in the particular month AND of a specific "Dimension". For that you essentially need to use COUNTIFS. (I am asuming here that the number of distinct value in "Dimension" is limited and relatively small)

Comment: So, does that mean that what I've been finding in other online sources is true?  That is, the stacked bar chart can't be done with my current structure?  It first needs to be aggregated?

Comment: I don't know which online sources you refer to (it would have been a good idea to make explicit references to them) but the short answer is yes. There is no way you are going to create a complex stacked bar chart in Excel from your current data structure without working on them first. Creating a chart from a pivot table might also be an option if you want to go down that route.